# how to pass dataset as a parameter to another url in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

```
private void import()
{  
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
  Export(ds);  
}

[WebMethod] 
public void Export(DataSet ds) 
{ 
    DataSet Ip_ds = new DataSet(); 
    Ip_ds = ds; // insert this data in table 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But there is something missing from your question. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), some samples, images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please spend time to post your question with relevant details. See [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) if you need any information on how to post questions.

Comment: private void import()
{  
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
  http:localhost//Api/Export(ds);  
}

Comment: i want to pass this dataset to another url

Comment: What do you mean by another `url`?

Comment: http:localhost//Api/Export(ds) -- pass the dataset result like this

Answer (score 0):

You dont  need to pass a whole dataset as a parameter in the url .you can just pass the unique identifiers of the dataset as a parameter in the url and then use that identifier to get the required values.

Comment: can you explain it briefly

Comment: Are you using web api?

Comment: yes . import function have 1 api & Export function have another api

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP POST method to post the data(Dataset) to the URL. You may need to use Newtonsoft JSON for serializing the Dataset.